# Crafting a SP to determine which columns make a table unique

Tags: database, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, etl

For numerous reasons you'll want to know which column(s) make the table unique. This is an easy job to do when you have tables with an actual PK or just a few columns.

However in this case I got a lot of huge tables (50+ columns) without any data types specified and thus no keys.
There are some options to get this information; parse the table with a specific tool or simply ask the owner/creator of the table what the composite key is.
This can prove to be a slow process. 
I want to see if I can determine what the composite key is for a table with a stored procedure.

I know for sure there has to be one for each table. This is because every row in each table is unique.

I've spend some time on google on this matter but I only come across ways to make composite keys etc.  Or ways to list tables with composite keys (only if they are already defined).

Basicly what I'm trying to create is a SP which takes a table name and returns me the columns which I could turn into a composite key.

Can anyone point me in the right direction because I'm kind of lost at the moment. 
I'm using SQL server 2014 in this project.

Comment: Is the composite key defined, or do you need to figure it out from the data? because if it's defined you only need to check some system tables like sys.indexes and sys.index_columns. If you need to figure it out from the data you are probably going to have to write a lot of tests. What version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: The key is not defined and I need to figure it out from the data itself. That's the tricky part in this. Currently I'm using SQL server 2014. I'm also more looking for the logic behind the issue.

Comment: What I have in mind is to use count(distinct) for every possible column combination until you find the combination that has the result as count(*). Of course, this will be extremely slow to do manually, but It's possible to automate it using dynamic SQL, building your query from data from sys.columns. I don't know if that's the best approach but that's the only one I can think of right now. I currently don't have the time to create a code sample for this so I'm not posting this as an answer, yet.

Comment: Logic? Take all suitable columns ([[n]var]char(not max), int), take all full or partial combinations of these, select count of records, grouped by partial set of columns - if record count is same, you have unique set.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - take the example in the question. There are 50+ columns and anywhere between 1 column and all 50 of them may be required to create the key. The number of combinations to test is staggering (2^50)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, well, I didn't say it's going to be easy, and of course, Arvo's comment might cut down the number of columns to check (though I wouldn't rule out date columns, for example). But as I said, that's the only thing I had in mind as of now. If you could think of a better solution, I would love to know about it.

Comment: Of course, to find the minimal composite key is going to be even harder - you could argue that if you know the rows are unique than a maximal composite key will contain all columns in the table....

Comment: SSIS already has a [Data Profiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/data-profiling-task) task to analyze data and detect unique candidates, value frequencies, column relations, etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know of this data profiler. However I never managed to pipe it to another application. The idea is when I manage to solve this I can dynamicly start creating tables just based on the data.

Comment: @ppijnenburg what do you mean "pipe"? The output is an XML file, you can simply read it. As for "just based on the data" you can't - what if there are *multiple* unique combinations? Even with a single combination, which *order* are you going to use? If you use a clustered index (the default for PKs), this will affect the physical order on disk, affecting query performance. Which means you want to know each column's distribution too. What if you want to add some auditing columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not most appropriate task for stored procedure, but with time it's doable. Unfortunately, straightforward complete solution takes quite a bit of time, too much, I'd say. Time complexity is about O(2^C), where C is number of columns, and each try takes quite a bit of time as well.

The general idea for complete solution is to iterate over column sets, every possible combination of table columns (in no particular order inside set). Then we check set for coupling, and get one with least columns from ones passing the test.

Good news, there is quick test for possible solution. Check for count(distinct)=count(*). If it's ok, you can at least use whole table as one bit key...

Bad news, it's doesn't solve the problem.

**But we can be greedy.**

Count unique values for each column and sort columns in decreasing order. If there is simple 1-column PK, it will be in first column(s).

Now we get columns in this order and add to set of columns. If multiplication of unique values for selected column 1..K is less than count(*), you can't get unique index out of them - go further.

Once we count enough possibilities, try to check count(distinct) for select over these columns with dynamic SQL. If it's not enough, go further.

Once we get enough columns to cover uniqness, we are nearly done. Now let's try to remove some columns from this set. Iterate from 1 to K and try column set (1..I-1, I+1..K). If it's still unique, remove this column from set and continue dropping columns.

A bit tricky to continue iteration properly after removal of column, but it's doable.

Once we tried to remove all columns of covering set, we are done.

It is not precise algorythm, so you'll have to check it manually, but at least you'll have something to start with and it has O(C*D) time complexity where C is number of columns and D is amount of data in the table.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your approach. I will start cooking something up tonight when I get back from work. And see what the exact impact will be.

Comment: That's a better solution than what I had in mind, though if Panagiotis Kanavos's answer checks out, it's probably better to use it instead of rolling your own. +1.

Comment: I'm going to try and set-up a test script tomorrow to see what the impact will be. Last night I was fighting the SSIS gods trying to use the build-in data profiler.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem in ETL projects - you get a file, table or other data source and have to guess about unique columns, sizes, distinct values, relations between columns, nullability etc.

SSIS already has a [Data Profiling Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/data-profiling-task) that can read a source (eg a table) and perform many of these checks. The one you need is `Candidate Key Profile`. This will check which column combinations can be used as keys or even *approximate* keys (ie not 100% unique).

This process takes a long time because the task has to read all the data and check all column combinations for uniqueness. The result is saved in a file that can be opened in the [Data Profile Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/data-profile-viewer) for analysis.

You can use multiple profiles at once to save time, eg to collect size, distribution and candidate keys in one go.

You can also use multiple profiling tasks to analyze multiple sources/tables at once, or put it in a loop container that profiles eg all files in a folder or all tables in a list.

Comment: I tried this last evening and I can confirm this will actually work as I managed to extract the data from the XML to use in table creation.

Comment: However the main reason why I don't want to use SISS packages is the fact that this needs manuallabor (or is it possible now a days to dynamicly generate packages? (Last time I checked was a couple years back and couldn't find a way of doing this))

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you just need an algorithm for it. If you do not have a PK, you could use the columns as key suspects that are used in indices.
You have to make sure your composite key is unique tablewise so have to query the data.
Here is what I thought:
0. query the row count of the table
1. choose a column that is suspicious to be a unique key
2. make a dictinct count query of that column for example top 1000 rows
3. if the result is 1000, the data is unique. in this case repeat the query with a greater number of rows, until you reach the row count of the table. if the result of the last query equals to the row count of the table you found your probably unique key.
4. if the result is lower than 1000, replenish the chosen column with another suspect making a composite key. with this key repeat from step 2.

This can be a slow and tedious work and you should consider that even with this, you cannot be sure you found the true unique key, just a key that is unique with the already existing data.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer since it *doesn't* actually answer the qeustion. SO is a Q&A site where answers are expected to be *answers* that will help other people that have the same problem in the future